# Match seconds word ONLY on a sentence if its STOP or stop or StOppp

Tags: java, regex

So the problem is that I need a regex that will match the second word only if its `stop` that means as well the `stopp` or `sstoooppp` followed by a space. I need to get that word I cant find any regex to do that as I have found some like the one that does half of the job which is this one

```
\b[STOP]+\ \b|\b[stop]+\ \b
```

but the problem with that is that it doesnt match the second word of a sentence and it matches everything that contains stop the other problem is it matches the `to` cause its `t` followed by `o` so it matches any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Justs use `[sS]+[tT]+[oO]+[pP]+`

Explanation:

`[sS]+` - match one or more of `s` or `S`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FSCRuW/1)

UPDATE: `^[^ ]+ [sS]+[tT]+[oO]+[pP]+`

[Updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/FSCRuW/2)

Comment: thank you for the fast response yea also one other problem is that I want to match it only if its the seconds word if a text comes like this `hello I want to stop my carrier` i don't want to match the stop there I want to match it only if it the second word of the entire text like this `hello stop my carrier now`

Comment: works perfect thank you very much time to study more of weird regex like the start of it :P